# invalid literal for int() with base 10: '106954.64'

Tags: python

I am trying to convert an object to numeric. But below is the error i have received:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '106954.64'
```

I have gone through lots of discussion in the forum, but could not get the logic behind this.

Below is the code:

```
train['Amount_EUR']=train['Amount_EUR'].astype(int)
```

Comment: Well, that's not an integer. Use `float` instead, or `Decimal`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse a string to a float or int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/how-do-i-parse-a-string-to-a-float-or-int)

Comment: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '#VALUE!'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to convert it to a float and then to int:
`print(int(float('106954.64')))`

Comment: how will i apply the logic as per your advice in a value column as it is a dataframe

Comment: train['Amount_EUR'].replace('106954.64',int(float('106954.64')),inplace=True)--- i hope this code can work out